# What's the easiest way to install OpenSSH 7.4 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, apt, openssh

On Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) box, what is the easiest way to install OpenSSH (`openssh-client`) that is higher than `7.2`?

I am aware that I could compile from source, but I was wondering if there's a way to avoid that.

Is there an officially maintained *ppa* for that?
I also tried `sudo apt-get install -t xenial-backports openssh-client`, but that doesn't have it either.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need 7.4 other than security? The security fixes get backported as patches against the 7.2 version in 16.04. If you need a specific newer feature for some reason, that's fine, but often people see newer version numbers in CVEs as how to fix a problem, when Ubuntu already has the fixes patched into the older version, via the security channel.

Comment: I need the `Include` option, which is available in 7.3 https://superuser.com/a/1142813/491655

Answer (score 0):

See instructions to upgrade SSH client to next possible Ubuntu version Yakkety 16.10 with provides SSH 7.3 (with `Include config.d/*` support):

```
echo "deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yakkety.list
apt-get update
apt-get install -y ssh
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yakkety.list
apt-get update
```

Answer (score -1):

An alternative approach is installing the debian packages (although this approach is not ppa related)

https://gist.github.com/stefansundin/0fd6e9de172041817d0b8a75f1ede677

Just bear in mind that by doing this outside of apt then future installation management is messed up. To see what this would affect you can run

```
apt-cache rdepends openssh-client
```

and then going forwards when installing one those affected packages you will most likely see an error about the original version of openssh-client being missing . At least that is the behaviour I observed during the writing of some ansible scripts (Initially I upgraded the openssh-client last in the scripts to get around this)

In the error output in that scenario I noticed the output suggested to

```
apt-get -f install
```

without specifying a package. I did this, it installed a few bits (which apparently were not to do with openssh-client), and somehow future installs which depend on openssh-client now go through fine without complaining about the fixed version dependency.